# pyYaml - Export without "-"

Tags: python, yaml

I need to export dict to yaml with pyyaml without the "-"

```
    export_dash_dict = {}
    export_dash_dict["dashboards"] = []
    for dashboard in dashboards_to_export:
        single_dashboard = {}
        single_dashboard[dashboard.title] = {}
        single_dashboard[dashboard.title]["owner"]          = dashboard.owner.username
        single_dashboard[dashboard.title]["description"]    = dashboard.description
        export_dash_dict["dashboards"].append(single_dashboard)

    final_yaml = yaml.dump(export_dash_dict, default_flow_style=False,default_style=None)
```

This is how pyyaml export my dict:

```
dashboards:
- Dashboard title 1:
    description: First
    owner: username1
- Dashboard title 2:
    description: Second
    owner: username2
```

Using an online parsed, this is what I get:

```
{
  "dashboards": [
    {
      "Dashboard title 1": {
        "owner": "username1", 
        "description": "First"
      }
    }, 
    {
      "Dashboard title 2": {
        "owner": "username2", 
        "description": "Second"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

But I need something like this:

```
dashboards:
 Dashboard title 1:
    description: First
    owner: username1
 Dashboard title 2:
    description: Second
    owner: username2
```

with the online parser:

```
{
  "dashboards": {
    "Dashboard title 2": {
      "owner": "username2", 
      "description": "Second"
    }, 
    "Dashboard title 1": {
      "owner": "username1", 
      "description": "First"
    }
  }
}
```

In this way I can avoid a entire level dept of data when I use yaml.load

Im using: default_flow_style=False parameters but I can't find a way to avoid "-"
Is that a standard of YAML?

Comment: You should not be using `yaml.load()` it is documented to be potentially unsafe. The onine parser shows you no list for you intended output, so why create them in your program in the first place if you don't want them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The yaml dump is correctly exporting your data structure.  You have a dictionary (`export_dash_dict`) with one key and one value.  The one key is `dashboards` and its value is a list with two elements.  The two elements are dictionaries (whose contents we won't go into here, but they have two key-value pairs).

The data structure you say that you would like to export is not a dictionary with one key/value pair where the value is a list, but rather a dictionary with *two* key-value pairs.  The first key is to be `Dashboard title 1` and its value is to be a dictionary (with two key-value pairs that we won't detail here).  The second key is to be `Dashboard title 2` and its value is to be a dictionary (with, again, two key-value pairs that we won't detail).

If you want `yaml.dump` to write such a data structure, you need to construct that data structure.

Comment: Thank you. This is the corret way to build the dict: 

`export_dash_dict = {}
    export_dash_dict["dashboards"] = {}
    for dashboard in dashboards_to_export:
        export_dash_dict["dashboards"][dashboard.title] = {}
        export_dash_dict["dashboards"][dashboard.title]["owner"]          = dashboard.owner.username
        export_dash_dict["dashboards"][dashboard.title]["description"]    = dashboard.description

    final_yaml = yaml.dump(export_dash_dict, default_flow_style=False,default_style=None)`

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to torek, this is the correct way to build the dict:

```
    export_dash_dict = {}
    export_dash_dict["dashboards"] = {}
    for dashboard in dashboards_to_export:
        export_dash_dict["dashboards"][dashboard.title] = {}
        export_dash_dict["dashboards"][dashboard.title]["owner"]          = dashboard.owner.username
        export_dash_dict["dashboards"][dashboard.title]["description"]    = dashboard.description

    final_yaml = yaml.dump(export_dash_dict, default_flow_style=False,default_style=None)
```